# How do I display binary field image on a PDF report?

Tags: python, odoo

How do I display a binary field image on a report in OpenERP? I just used a .sxw to convert it into a .rml. I want to display that image in a pdf report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

edit your rml file. Im using 'image_field' as the binary field.

```
<image>[[ obj.image_field or removeParentNode('image') ]]</image>
```

you can also specify the position

```
<image x="21.3cm" y="47.6cm" height="40.0" >[[ obj.image_field or removeParentNode('image') ]]</image>
```

Answer (score 2):

For printing an image saved on the database as a `binary` field for qweb report,

```
<img t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % o.your_image_field"/>
```

Comment: Tnx for nice answer +1,  is it possible hide image tag if binary field in database empty?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following .sxw expression:

```
[[ obj.image_field and setTag('para','image',{'width':'80.0','height':'80.0'}) ]] [[ obj.image_field ]]
```

this get translated by the engine to:

```
<para rml_tag="obj.image_field and setTag('para','image',{'width':'80.0','height':'80.0'})">[[ '' ]] [[ obj.image_field ]]</para>
```